# makefile executable permission denied

Tags: build, permissions, makefile

I have a makefile that creates an executeable ("ls") and places it in a folder called bin. However when I try to run that executable afterwards I get the error: 
"-bash: bin/ls: Permission denied"

```
VPATH = src
CC = g++
CFLAGS =-c -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic

all:    clean rshell

rshell: ls.cpp
        $ mkdir -p ./bin
        $ $(CC) $(CFLAGS) src/ls.cpp -o bin/ls
clean:
        rm -rf bin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem says exactly what goes wrong: your newly created `ls` executable is missing the executable bit.

In your case, you explicitely disable the linker, which is almost never a good approach, unless you really really really know what you're doing. My blind guess is that your source code is missing a `int main(int, char**)` function, and thus linking would give you an error (because you can't build an executable with the standard linker setup that doesn't have exactly one `main`). However, with `-c` in your `CFLAGS`, you neither get the warning nor the executable file.

EDIT: `file ls` will show something like

```
ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

on a binary compiled with `-c`, whilst a fully fledged executable will have

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=6cf260a90064be20cfa17ff5fefd7040254f79e1, not stripped
```

Notice how one file is `executable` ;) furthermore, it's linked against *something*, that something including the startup code that is executed before your `ls`'s `main` function. Without that, the OS wouldn't know how to run your program.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the `-c` flag; what's wrong is putting it in `CFLAGS`. Normally, you'd use `-c -o file.o` to produce object files which could then be linked together to produce the executable; that's useful with large projects where you don't want to recompile all of the files every time you made a little change to one of them. `gcc` sets `x` permission only to executable files; `-c` produces files without have `x` permission. `chmod +x` won't help because the files are also not executable images, but it will produce a different error when you try to run the file.

Comment: @rici exactly! Thanks for elaborating.